# No instance for (Num [Integer]) arising from the literal ‘1’

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

```
plus1 :: [Integer] ->  [Integer] -> [Integer] 
plus1 (x:xs) remain  
    | (x==0) && (remain==1) = [1] ++ (plus1 xs (remain-1) )
    | (x==1) && (remain==1) = [0] ++ (plus1 xs remain)
    | (x==0) && (remain==0) = [0] ++ (plus1 xs 0)
    | (x==1) && (remain==0) = [1] ++ (plus1 xs 0)
    |  otherwise = []
```

• No instance for (Num [Integer]) arising from the literal ‘1’

• In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘1’

In the second argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘(remain == 1)’

In the expression: (x == 0) && (remain == 1)

Comment: your type signature says that `remain` should be `[Integer]` but you are comparing it with `==` to `1` with is `Integer`. Perhaps `remain`'s type signature was intended to be `plus1 :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]`?

Comment: My all thanks, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your type signature says that `remain` should be `:: [Integer]` but you are comparing it with `==` to `1` with is `Integer`. Perhaps your type signature was intended to be `plus1 :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]`

Comment: pulled from Mateusz's comment so this question has an answer.